# Laravel: with() method, refering to a parent model attribute?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Is it possible to refer to a "parent" model attribute within the with() method ?
Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
    $slug = $this->property('slug');

     $post = new Post;

     $post = $post->where('slug', $slug)
                  ->with(['categories' => function ($query) {
                             $query->where('category_attribute', '!=', 'post_attribute');
                         }]);
```

but it doesn't work, it seems like the post attribute is not recognized.

```
class Post extends Model
{   
   ...
   public $belongsToMany = [
     'categories' => [
         'Codalia\PluginName\Models\Category',
         'table' => 'codalia_pluginname_categories_posts',
         'order' => 'name'
       ]
   ];
   ...
 }


class Category extends Model
{ 
   ...  
   public $belongsToMany = [
      'posts' => ['Codalia\PluginName\Models\Post',
       'table' => 'codalia_pluginname_categories_posts',
       'order' => 'published_at desc',
   ],
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Do you have the relationship categories registered in your model Post?

Comment: As well, could you please share a bit more the structure of your Post and Category models?

Comment: Yes I have the relationship categories registered in my Post model.

Comment: I think it may be better to do a join query for this specific case

Comment: Yes I guess it's the best option but I have to "foreach" the result to bring the categories together into an array as does with(). 
It's really a shame that the with() method doesn't offer more flexibility.

Comment: Untested: can you try `$query->where('categories.attribute', '!=', 'posts.attribute');`

Comment: Already did. It doesn't work...